# SonarQube Technical Debt management with Quality Gate

Tags: java, sonarqube, software-quality, sonarqube5.3

Configuring a custom Quality Gate, the default SonarQube Way has been taken as initial reference and further adjusted and customized (adding further checks).   Our current quality gate looks as following (old version vs current version):

```
Blocker issues:             error threshold at 0
Complexity/class:           error threshold at 12
Complexity/file:            error threshold at 12
Complexity/function         error threshold at 2
Coverage                    error threshold at 100 >> changed to 65
Critical issues             error threshold at 0
Duplicated lines (%)        error threshold at 5
Info issues                 error threshold at 10
Major issues                error threshold at 50
Minor issues                error threshold at 100
Overall coverage            error threshold at 100 >> changed to 65
Public documented API (%)   error threshold at 50
Skipped Unit tests          error threshold at 0
Technical Debts             error threshold at 10d >> change to (?? < 10)
Unit test errors            error threshold at 0
Unit test failures          error threshold at 0
```

The main point is about the Technical Debts days, which should be enforced from 10 to something smaller, given that other checks have been relaxed (complexity and coverage). This is indeed reasonable: relaxing some rules you should have more margin for controlled technical debt and hence shorter threshold for the number of accumulated days for uncontrolled technical debt.

However, the overall quality gate should somehow (mathematically?) follow a certain proportion.

**Question**: how to calculate the most appropriate technical debt threshold given the relaxations above?

From an [old article](http://www.sonarqube.org/evaluate-your-technical-debt-with-sonar/) (2009, hence most probably not applicable any longer) the following formula has been deducted:

```
TechDebt = (cost_to_fix_one_block * duplicated_blocks) + \
     (cost_to fix_one_violation * mandatory_violations) + \
     (cost_to_comment_one_API * public_undocumented_api) + \
     (cost_to_cover_one_of_complexity * uncovered_complexity_by_tests) + \
     (cost_to_split_a_method * function_complexity_distribution) + \
     (cost_to_split_a_class * class_complexity_distribution)
```

Note: `\` added for readability.

However, there are too many unknown variables to make a proper calculation, yet it is not covering all of the quality gate items above (again, it's an old reference).

Other more recent [sources](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions) explain in details concerned items, but not how to adjust values **in a proportionated manner**.

The `sonar.technicalDebt.developmentCost` (*Admin* / *Configuration* / *Technical Debt*) has a default value of **30** minutes, which means 1 LOC (cost to develop 1 line of code) = 30, but still not at the granularity level of the variables above nor useful in this case.

Comment: Your question illustrates just too well the nonsense of calculating technical debt and how it helps absolutely nothing in improving code quality. I strongly recommend this short blog post to you: https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/technical-debt-metaphor/

Comment: @NilsGöde I see the point, on the other hand if a well-known tool offers it as part of an overall profile, the tool should also automatically adjust it when changing some variables, this is an important missing feature imho. Otherwise indeed the danger is that the community could start ignoring it.

Comment: Are you asking what level of technical debt is allowable in an application or how to include that allowable level (which scales with the project) in your quality gate?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam what I'm asking is actually: we have relaxed few points of the quality gate, now according to these relaxations how should we calculate the tech debt? I believe there is a certain balance across these values, especially towards the tech debt, hence changing any of them should reasonably affect its value. But how to adjust it in a coherent manner? (we can adjust it based on our common sense, but that could become a point of debate later on, we could set it from 10 to 4, but why 4 days given these relaxations? why not 3 or 6?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Quality Gate is made up of a set of conditions. Your list of conditions is far longer than the one in the default quality gate. Most of the conditions you list aren't in the default quality gate. It looks instead as though you've edited the default thresholds of a number of rules.

And in a sense, you're talking about apples and oranges.

A Technical Debt threshold can be included in a Quality Gate, but by default is not. Instead, the Technical Debt Ratio on New Code is included in the default QG. But the concept of the Technical Debt Ratio does have bearing on your question. If you set a hard threshold on technical debt in a quality gate, small projects will have an easier time passing the QG than large projects. If you instead use the Technical Debt Ratio or the Technical Debt Ratio on New Code (recommended) then you're setting your quality gate on a ratio based on code base size versus technical debt. So every project has the same chance of passing or failing. The formula is this:

> Remediation cost / (Cost to develop 1 line of code * Number of lines of code)

with, an estimated line development cost of 30 min. This value is editable, BTW: *Administration > Technical Debt > Development cost*

The default quality gate includes a Technical Debt Ratio on New Code error threshold of 5.

Comment: You're right, just downloaded a brand new sonarqube 5.3 installation and indeed the default quality gate only provides few thresholds (Coverage on new code at 80, New blocker issues at 0, New Critical issues at 0, Technical Debt Ratio on New code at 5). Same in sonarqube 5.4 while in 5.5 it has slightly changed labels (New bugs/vulnerabilities instead of Blocker/Critical).

Comment: I confirm we customized the default quality gate as well, sorry about this incorrect initial information, I will fix it in the question  (and award the bounty). Hence, in general you would suggest not to use the Technical Debt check for a quality gate, we will definitely consider it then. However, if we really had to, what would you suggest as way of reasonably setting/calculating it?

Comment: I would suggest focusing on the ratio instead. 10 days of tech debt in a 100 line project? Big trouble. 10 days of tech debt in a 100k LoC project? Give yourself a pat on the back.

Comment: Thanks for these feedbacks, although not answering directly the initial question, they made us move forward and consider additional scenarios, hence I would consider it accepted answer and award the bounty.